# Haskell Let Expressions Evaluation

Tags: haskell, stream, expression, evaluation, let

I am doing practice problems that evaluate a let expression and I don't understand the output of this one.

Here is the expression:

```
let a = 2
    b = 1:[i * 2 | i <- b]
    f a = 1:[i * a | i <- (f a)]
in take (a+2) (f (head (tail b) ))
```

The output is supposed to be [1,2,4,8]. Could someone please explain step by step why this is the output

Answer (score 6):

Here's a step-by-step explanation:

```
let a = 2
    b = 1:[i * 2 | i <- b]
    f a = 1:[i * a | i <- (f a)]
in take (a+2) (f (head (tail b) ))
```

There's two different variables called `a` in there, and one shadows the other, so first let's rename one of them to avoid accidentally mixing them up:

```
let outer_a = 2
    b = 1:[i * 2 | i <- b]
    f a = 1:[i * a | i <- (f a)]
in take (outer_a+2) (f (head (tail b) ))
```

Now we can substitute in `outer_a` and evaluate the `+`:

```
let b = 1:[i * 2 | i <- b]
    f a = 1:[i * a | i <- (f a)]
in take 4 (f (head (tail b) ))
```

Rewrite the list comprehensions in terms of `map`:

```
let b = 1:map (* 2) b
    f a = 1:map (* a) (f a)
in take 4 (f (head (tail b) ))
```

Use `iterate` instead of explicit recursion:

```
let b = iterate (* 2) 1
    f a = iterate (* a) 1
in take 4 (f (head (tail b) ))
```

Evaluate the first two steps of `b`:

```
let b = 1:2:iterate (* 2) 4
    f a = iterate (* a) 1
in take 4 (f (head (tail b) ))
```

Substitute in `b`:

```
let f a = iterate (* a) 1
in take 4 (f (head (tail (1:2:iterate (* 2) 4)) ))
```

Evaluate `tail`:

```
let f a = iterate (* a) 1
in take 4 (f (head (2:iterate (* 2) 4) ))
```

Evaluate `head`:

```
let f a = iterate (* a) 1
in take 4 (f 2)
```

Substitute in `f a`:

```
take 4 (iterate (* 2) 1)
```

Evaluate `iterate` a few times:

```
take 4 (1:2:4:8:iterate (* 2) 16)
```

Evaluate `take`:

```
[1,2,4,8]
```

And we're done.

Comment: This is actually a practice problem for an exam coming up and the solution was said to be [1,2,4,8]

Comment: @csj Then either the practice problem is wrong, or you copied it down wrong. If you type into GHCi exactly what you posted in your question (after doing `:set +m` of course), it will give you `[1,3,9,27]`.

Comment: oh I'm so sorry it was supposed to be * not + for b, I just edited the question

Comment: `f a` returns same values as `iterate (*a) 1` of course, but it does it in a very different, radically slower way (is quadratic instead of linear). this can be seen if we reduce it step by step.

Answer (score 1):

To see what's going on we carefully name each entity as it comes into being:

```
let a   = 2
    b   = 1 : [i * 2 | i <- b]
    f a = 1 : [i * a | i <- f a]
in  take (a+2) (f (head (tail b)))
==
let b        = (b1:bs1)
    (b1:bs1) = 1 : [i * 2 | i <- b]
in  take 4 (f (head (tail b)))
==
let b1  = 1
    bs1 = [i * 2 | i <- (b1:bs1)]
in  take 4 (f (head bs1))
==
let b1  = 1
    bs1 = [i * 2 | i <- [b1]] ++ [i * 2 | i <- bs1]
in  take 4 (f (head bs1))
==
let bs1 = [i * 2 | i <- [1]] ++ [i * 2 | i <- bs1]
in  take 4 (f (head bs1))
==
let bs1      = (b2:bs2)
    (b2:bs2) = [1 * 2] ++ [i * 2 | i <- bs1]
in  take 4 (f b2)
==
let (b2:bs2) = 2 : [i * 2 | i <- (b2:bs2)]
in  take 4 (f b2)
==
let bs2      =     [i * 2 | i <- (2:bs2)]
    f a      = 1 : [i * a | i <- f a]     -- same as before
in  take 4 (f 2)
==
let xs       = f 2
    f 2      = 1 : [i * 2 | i <- f 2] 
in  take 4 xs
==
let (x1:xs1) = 1 : [i * 2 | i <- f 2]
in  take 4 (x1:xs1)
==
let xs1      =     [i * 2 | i <- f 2]
in  take 4 (1:xs1)
==
let xs1      =     [i * 2 | i <- f 2]
in  1 : take 3 xs1
==
let (x2:xs2) =     [i * 2 | i <- (y1:ys1)]
    (y1:ys1) = 1 : [i * 2 | i <- f 2]
in  1 : take 3 (x2:xs2)
==
let (x2:xs2) =     [i * 2 | i <- (1:ys1)]
    ys1      =     [i * 2 | i <- f 2]
in  1 : take 3 (x2:xs2)
==
let (x2:xs2) = 2 : [i * 2 | i <- ys1]
    ys1      =     [i * 2 | i <- f 2]
in  1 : take 3 (x2:xs2)
==
let xs2      =     [i * 2 | i <- ys1]
    ys1      =     [i * 2 | i <- f 2]
in  1 : take 3 (2:xs2)
==
let xs2      =     [i * 2 | i <- ys1]
    ys1      =     [i * 2 | i <- f 2]
in  1 : 2 : take 2 xs2
==
let (x3:xs3) =     [i * 2 | i <- (y2:ys2)]
    (y2:ys2) =     [i * 2 | i <- (z1:zs1)]
    (z1:zs1) = 1 : [i * 2 | i <- f 2]
in  1 : 2 : take 2 (x3:xs3)
==
let (x3:xs3) =     [i * 2 | i <- (y2:ys2)]
    (y2:ys2) = 2 : [i * 2 | i <- zs1]
    zs1      =     [i * 2 | i <- f 2]
in  1 : 2 : take 2 (x3:xs3)
==
let (x3:xs3) = 4 : [i * 2 | i <- ys2]
    ys2      =     [i * 2 | i <- zs1]
    zs1      =     [i * 2 | i <- f 2]
in  1 : 2 : take 2 (x3:xs3)
==
let xs3      =     [i * 2 | i <- ys2]
    ys2      =     [i * 2 | i <- zs1]
    zs1      =     [i * 2 | i <- f 2]
in  1 : 2 : 4 : take 1 xs3
==
let (x4:xs4) =     [i * 2 | i <- (y3:ys3)]
    (y3:ys3) =     [i * 2 | i <- (z2:zs2)]
    (z2:zs2) =     [i * 2 | i <- (w1:ws1)]
    (w1:ws1) = 1 : [i * 2 | i <- f 2]
in  1 : 2 : 4 : take 1 (x4:xs4)
==
let (x4:xs4) =     [i * 2 | i <- (y3:ys3)]
    (y3:ys3) =     [i * 2 | i <- (z2:zs2)]
    (z2:zs2) = 2 : [i * 2 | i <- ws1]
    ws1      =     [i * 2 | i <- f 2]
in  1 : 2 : 4 : take 1 (x4:xs4)
==
let (x4:xs4) =     [i * 2 | i <- (y3:ys3)]
    (y3:ys3) = 4 : [i * 2 | i <- zs2]
    zs2      =     [i * 2 | i <- ws1]
    ws1      =     [i * 2 | i <- f 2]
in  1 : 2 : 4 : take 1 (x4:xs4)
==
let (x4:xs4) = 8 : [i * 2 | i <- ys3]
    ys3      =     [i * 2 | i <- zs2]
    zs2      =     [i * 2 | i <- ws1]
    ws1      =     [i * 2 | i <- f 2]
in  1 : 2 : 4 : take 1 (x4:xs4)
==
    1 : 2 : 4 : 8 : take 0 xs4
==
    1 : 2 : 4 : 8 : []
```

In the above derivation we used the property of list comprehensions where

```
  [ ... | ... <- (xs   ++   ys)] 
=== 
  [ ... | ... <- xs ] ++ [ ... | ... <- ys]
```

so that

```
  [ ... | ... <- (x : ys)] 
=== 
  [ ... | ... <- [x] ] ++ [ ... | ... <- ys]
```

`f a` produces the same results as `iterate (* a) 1`, but operationally it is very much different. While the latter is linear, the former is a quadratic function, w.r.t. its time complexity.

To see what it means in practice, compare the timings for:

```
> f 1.01 !! 4000
1.9297236994732192e17
(1.28 secs, 1614556912 bytes)

> iterate (* 1.01) 1 !! 4000
1.9297236994732192e17
(0.00 secs, 12990984 bytes)
```